# How to introduce AngularJS into an existing app that uses Backbone & JQuery?

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application using jQuery and Backbone and I am finding myself writing a lot of boilerplate code over and over again. I have been looking into AngularJS and it is a much better fit for my application than backbone and jQuery. I would like to introduce Angular on a few pages and gradually convert from Backbone to Angular provided I don't run into problems with Angular.

Is it possible to use AngularJS on a page that also uses Backbone & JQuery?

Comment: Hi ams, I'm in a similar situation and curious how the story ended for you.  Regret the migration?  What are the key lessons learned especially switching off a router using pushstate.

Comment: @JStark We stuck with Backbone we had too much existing backbone code 30,000+ lines to dump and start again from scratch, also we could not afford the time to properly ramp up with AngularJS. So we are taking a wait and see approach we keep making our backbone code better each day and focused more on delivering business value. We are hopping that while we wait AngularJS keeps getting better, and maybe in early 2014 the business and technical conditions might be right to make a switch to Angular. But at this point I would not start a new project with Backbone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer, I believe, is 'YES'. Angular does have an inline template construct that should help you gradually migrate from backbone and once you are ready, you can move those inlines into external partials. Which, IMHO, will be a big plus for readability/maintainability. Angular also has a mechanism for associating an app (module) with only a subset of your page (a div element). I've used this technique with .NET apps. I have done some backbone dev, and am pretty sure you can make the 2 coexist.

Comment: Thanks Dan, do you know if it is possible to have two totally seperate ng-app on the same page?

Comment: I haven't found need for it but just tried and it does not seem to work. What is the use case for having multiple ng-apps?

Comment: build a portal type UI with different parts of the screen being different apps.

Comment: I think reusability of this nature is best suited by using directives. Take a look at http://angular-ui.github.com/ (I am a contributing member) maybe that will give you some ideas.

Comment: UPDATED: I stand corrected. You CAN have multiple ng-apps, it's just that you have to use code instead of declaratively. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Gjyaq/

Comment: Yep, you can have multiple ng-app on a single page, check out AngularJS homepage, every example is a standalone app, running all on a single page. But it requires manual bootstrap + little bit code (there are services, eg. $location, that you only can have one instance per page)